# ¿Como agregar dos animaciones a una misma etiqueta?

Tags: javascript, css, condiciones, animación, animate.css

Tengo el siguiente problema y la siguiente duda. Tengo dos condicionales, en donde se agregan animaciones, "fadeOutRigth", "fadeInRight", "ninguna", "fadeInLeft". **Lo que quiero realizar es que imag, salga con un fadeOutRight, luego entre imag2 con un fadeInRight, próximamente salga imag2 con un fadeOutLeft y por último entre imag con un fadeInLeft.** Digamos que lo único que no pude lograr es que imag2 salga con un fadeOutLeft, de todas formas no logro comprender por que cuando le agrego la clase "animacionDos" a img2, se termina realizando la animación en img, eso me desorienta bastante. Bueno en conclusión me gustaría que sean 4 animaciones como expliqué anteriormente(lo dejo en negrita). Se ve raro al ejecutar porque no está preparado el codigo para tan poca pantalla pero se puede clickear igual en la imagen.

```js
var imagen = document.getElementById("imag");
var imagDos = document.getElementById("imag2");
let contadorClick = 0;

function cambioId() {
  imag.id = "imag2";   
  document.getElementById("uno").id = "unoDespues";
  document.getElementById("padreOculto").id = "padreVisible";
};
function cambioIdDos() {
  imag2.id = "imag";  

};

const getDatos = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(cambioId());
  }, 2000);
});
}
const getDatosDos = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(cambioIdDos());
  }, 2000);
});
}

imagen.addEventListener("click", function cambiarImag() {
    contadorClick++;
    console.log(contadorClick);
    if(contadorClick>=4){
        contadorClick = 0;
    }
    if(contadorClick%2 != 0) {
        document.getElementById("imag").classList.add("animacion"); /* fadeOutRight */
        document.getElementById("imag").classList.remove("animacionDos"); /* fadeInLeft */
        getDatos();
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("imag2").classList.add("animacionDos"); /* fadeInLeft */
        document.getElementById("imag2").classList.remove("animacion"); /* fadeOutRight */
        document.getElementById("unoDespues").id = "uno";
        document.getElementById("padreVisible").id = "padreOculto";
        getDatosDos();
    }
  })
```

```css
    .contenedorsec {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #uno {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "contit imag imag"
    "contit imag imag";
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 93);
}
#unoDespues {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 2.5fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "contit imag imag"
    "contit padreVisible padreVisible";
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 93);
}

.contit { grid-area:contit; }
#padreVisible { grid-area:padreVisible; }
#imag { grid-area:imag; }
.contit {
    width: 3em;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 30%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.contit h1 {
    color: whitesmoke;
}
#padreOculto {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#padreVisible {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    width: 13em;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: wheat;
    animation:fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
#imag {
    width: 12em;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-top: 10em;
    border-radius: 60%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }
 #imag2 {
    width: 5em;
    margin-left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 5em;
    margin-top: 10em;
    border-radius: 0;
    animation:fadeInRight;
    animation-duration: 4s;
 }
 #texto {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
 /* ************************* */
 .animacion {
    animation:fadeOutRight;
    animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 .animacionDos {
    animation:fadeInLeft;
    animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 .animacionSalir {
    animation:fadeOutLeft;
    animation-duration: 2s;
 }
```

```html
<head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <title>Document</title>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" 
            rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rampart+One&display=swap" 
            rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"                         
            rel="stylesheet"
               integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"             
            crossorigin="anonymous">
               <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" 
            rel="stylesheet">
           <link rel="stylesheet" 
           href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
        </head>
<body>   
               <div class="contenedorsec" id="uno">
                <!-- SUBTITULO -->
                <div class="contit">
                   <h1 id="tituloUno"><br>¿<br>Q<br>U<br>&nbspI<br>E<br>N<br><br> S<br>O<br>Y<br>?</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="padreOculto">
                   <p id="texto"></p>
                 </div>
                <img src="https://i0.wp.com/imagenesparapeques.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Mario-Bros-png-transparente.png?ssl=1" alt="" id="imag">
               </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste cambiar el orden de aplicación de las animaciones? Es decir, primero hacer el `.remove` y luego hacer el `.add`. Actualmente lo hacés a la inversa.

Comment: @padaleiana sisi. Es más al principio lo tenía al revéz, lo cambié para probar.  Igual estoy casi seguro que se ejecuta todo el código en el condicional primero y después se pasa la orden, es decir que el orden no modifica nada (creo por lo que sé y tengo entendido, me puedo equivocar)

Comment: Solo dejo un voto a favor para mientras tanto (lleva tiempo analizar). Por cierto, para que se vea la imagen, borrá el _Enter_ de la url de la imagen :) (específicamente entre "wp-" y "content").

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias, ahí lo modifiqué!

Answer (score 2):

Las animaciones no se pueden asignar una tras otra, aunque hay opciones (en teoría), pero esto no funciona:

```
document.getElementById("imag").classList.add("animacion");
document.getElementById("imag").classList.remove("animacionDos");
```

Debes esperar a que termine la animación para poder ejecutar la que sigue y puedes hacerlo escuchando [eventos de animación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#usando_eventos_de_animaci%C3%B3n):

```js
let divRojo = document.querySelector('#rojo');

document.querySelector('#animar').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Asignar primera animación
    divRojo.classList.add('derecha');
});

// Ejecutar cuando finalice la animación
divRojo.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
    // ¿Tiene la primera animación?
    if(divRojo.classList.contains('derecha')) {
        // Eliminar primera animación
        divRojo.classList.remove('derecha');
        // Asignar la siguiente
        divRojo.classList.add('izquierda');
    } else {
        // Si fue la segunda, limpiar para que pueda funcionar otra vez
        divRojo.classList.remove('izquierda');
    }
});
```

```css
#rojo {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.derecha {
    animation-name: moverDer;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.izquierda {
    animation-name: moverIzq;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes moverDer {
    0% { left: 0; }
    100% { left: 200px; }
}
@keyframes moverIzq {
    0% { left: 200px; }
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="rojo"></div>
<button id="animar">Animar</button>
```